# Get data from PHP file on click of a button

Tags: php, jquery

When you load the page, I have two separate divs that get images randomly from a database then echo them as the background-image. I also get other data that comes along with the image.

I need to get data from a new PHP file and change the background-image of a div on click of a button (so that you don't need to refresh the page).

In getnew.php:

```
$select = mysqli_select_db($conn, "database"); 

$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM photos ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1");
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$img1link = $row['link'];
$rating1 = $row['rating'];
$s1 = $row['sigma'];

$result2 = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM photos ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1");
$row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc();
$img2link = $row2['link'];
$rating2 = $row2['rating'];
$s2 = $row2['sigma'];
```

In main.php:

```
$("#button").on("click",function(){
    //
})
```

As I understand it you use jQuery's $.get to fetch the data from getnew.php but how exactly can I then use the data to change the background-image without having to refresh the page?

For example: `style="background-image: url('<?php echo $img1link ?>')">`

Comment: You will get lot of tutorial for this if you search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use ajax, send data from the server and parse it at the client

Here is a code sample based on your snippet

In getnew.php:

```
$select = mysqli_select_db($conn, "database"); 
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM photos ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 2");
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$img1link = $row['link'];
$rating1 = $row['rating'];
$s1 = $row['sigma'];
$row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc();
$img2link = $row2['link'];
$rating2 = $row2['rating'];
$s2 = $row2['sigma'];
echo json_encode(array('img1'=>$img1link,'img2'=>$img2link));
```

In main.php:

```
$("#button").on("click",function(){
    $.getJSON("getnew.php",function(data){
    //use data.img2 and data.img1 and set the background
    // for example: $('#someDiv').css('background-image',"url('"+data.img1+"')");
   });
})
```

Comment: It's giving me Uncaught syntax error: Unexpected token o as an error.

Comment: If my response was helpful please vote up or accept it as an answer. debugging your code falls out of the scope of this question.

Comment: Appears to work now, but the image flicks back and forth between the new and old

Answer (score 0):

use JQuery CSS codes..as you are able to fetch the data from a page, pass the image path in jquery.css code, it will do as per your desire.

Try to analyze the code

Place it in a finction which will be called on click of the function:
on success you may use css like code:
This is just an example in ajax/jquery

```
 $.ajax("signin.php", {
                            data: {
                                login:  login,
                                pass:   pass
                            },
                            success: function(data)
                            {
                                //alert(data);
                                if (data==1)
                                {
                                    s$("#login").animate({   opacity: 1,top: '49%' }, 200,function(){
         $('.userbox').show().animate({ opacity: 1 }, 500);
            $("#login").animate({   opacity: 0,top: '60%' }, 500,function(){
                $(this).fadeOut(200,function(){
                  $(".text_success").slideDown();
                  $("#successLogin").animate({opacity: 1,height: "200px"},500);                  
                });                           
             }) 
     }) 

                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    alert(data);
                                    setTimeout( "unloading()", 1000 );
                                    showError('OOPS..please check the credentials..');
                                }
                            },
                            error: function()
                            {
                                //alert(data);
                                showError('OOPS..Error in Connection..');
                            },
                            type: "POST"
                      });
```

Comment: I'm not exactly how to use $.get with what I'm doing though.

Comment: I've tried but I'm still unsure. For example this one at W3 schools: http://puu.sh/hEzSW/f083e3bbd4.png - I'm not sure how to relate this to my own problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick script, but hope it helps:

in getnew.php

```
$select = mysqli_select_db($conn, "database"); 
function get_random_image(){
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM photos ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1");
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $result=[
        'link' => $row['link'],
        'rating' => $row['rating'],
        'sigma' => $row['sigma'] 
        ];
    return $result;
}

if($_POST['request']=='get_random_image'){
    $r = array();
    array_push($r, get_random_image());
    array_push($r, get_random_image());

    echo json_encode($r);
}
```

in javascript file:

```
$("#button").on("click",function(){
    show_image();
})

function show_image(){
    var response = get_data("get_random_image");

    response = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
    $.each( response, function( key, value ) {
        // do something with the data like this:
        $('.image').append('<img src="'+value.link+'">');
    }
}

function get_data(requested_action)
{
    var data=$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '../getnew.php',  // relative path to the php file
        data: {
            request:requested_action
        }, 
        async: false,
        dataType: 'json'
    });
    var msg= data.responseText;
    return msg;
}
```

Comment: That seems a little bit complex for me to understand (new to coding), Uri Goren's answer to this below seems easier for me to get, but it's giving me an error. Can you see why?

Comment: do you get the error in the console? did you try console.log(data)? to see what you get?  To see the console ouput right-click anywhere in the page and choose inspect element (firebug extension for mozilla)

Comment: His solution gives me "Uncaught syntax error: Unexpected token o" as an error.